# Webツールのリリース、公開について

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, grunt

Webツール（HTMLとCSSとJavascriptで作ったブラウザで動くツール）を作りました。
他のデベロッパーさんにも広く使ってほしいのですが、どのようにリリース、公開するのが良いでしょうか。
一般的なやり方や、人気なやり方を教えてください。
また、できればその方法について、実際にリリース、公開までの流れがわかる資料があれば教えていただけると嬉しいです。
なお今現在は、特にパッケージ化などせず、ソースをそのままGithubに置いて公開しています。

一応 "npm publish" というものを少し調べてみたのですが、これはサーバサイド（Node.js）専用ですか？ よくわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Webツール（HTMLとCSSとJavascriptで作ったブラウザで動くツール）

ということですので、ブラウザでアクセスして利用するツールかと思います。
この場合、他の人に使ってもらうには、誰でもブラウザでアクセスできるようにする、つまり**インターネット上にツールを公開する**ことがリリースに相当します。

昔ながらの方法はいわゆるレンタルサーバー（[さくらのレンタルサーバ](https://www.sakura.ne.jp/)など）を契約して、そこに作ったものをアップロードするというものですが、現在ではより楽な方法があります。

すでにGitHubをお使いとのことですので、**GitHub Pages**か**Netlify**をおすすめします。
これらはどちらも無料で利用可能で、設定画面から初期設定を行うと、自動的にGitHubに上げた内容をインターネットに公開できるものです。
これらのキーワードで検索すれば情報が出てくるかとは思いますが、参考になりそうな資料を探しておきました。

- **GitHub Pages**について: https://www.tam-tam.co.jp/tipsnote/html_css/post11245.html
- **Netlify**について: https://qiita.com/sugo/items/2ee64887d682b0dae635

これらの方法で、インターネット上にツールを公開することは可能です。しかし、それをデベロッパー達に広く使ってもらえるかどうかは残念ながら別の問題です。
使ってもらうには宣伝するしかありませんが、宣伝にはとくに決まったやり方はありません。思いつく手段の限りを尽くして宣伝しましょう。

---

なお、`npm publish`については、node.jsではなくブラウザ上で動くものも対象です。
しかし、これはいわゆる**ライブラリ**や**モジュール**、つまり他の人のプログラムに組み込んで使ってもらうためのものをアップロードする場所ですので、今回のように単体で動作するツールをアップロードするのには向いていません。